# How to run PHP files as another user with Apache and FastCGI?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fastcgi

As per older questions, such as [using mod_fcgid instead of mod_php](https://serverfault.com/questions/215261/using-mod-fcgid-instead-of-mod-php) and [PHP as CGI or Apache Module?](https://serverfault.com/questions/36867/php-as-cgi-or-apache-module) (and *tangentially* some [other](https://serverfault.com/questions/22156/what-could-cause-apache2-to-not-run-index-php-files-through-php-fastcgi-handler) [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/110490/local-htaccess-strangely-allowed-running-php-in-cgi-fastcgi-mode-in-apache-under)) I came to an understanding that running PHP as CGI or FastCGI would make my .php files be ran as the *owner* instead of the *apache* user (user that runs the Apache).

The `phpinfo();` function states that `Server API = CGI/FastCGI`

However, when I test the running user it is still *apache* ie. `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` returns *apache*.

I've also tried what [Jeremy Bouse suggested](https://serverfault.com/questions/215261/using-mod-fcgid-instead-of-mod-php/215647#215647) in a question I've mentioned, but the PHP `whoami` still returns *apache*.

---

**Should the fact that phpinfo's "Server API" equals "CGI/FastCGI" be adequate for regular users to run the php-files as the owner?**

(Does it even indicate that PHP is not running with mod_php?)

Or are there some admin tasks still to be done or something that is probably misconfigured?

Comment: Here's an answer to a similar question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30191

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO the (more recent and) best way to run PHP FastCGI is using [PHP-FPM](http://php-fpm.org/), which among the many options also permits to use different users for different websites.

From the [official website](http://php-fpm.org/):

> Ability to start workers with
>   different uid/gid/chroot/environment
>   and different php.ini (replaces
>   safe_mode)

But using FastCGI by itself is not enough to use the owner of the file (and there's no such thing as "automatically using the owner of the file": you have to **actually configure it** virtual host by virtual host (or as you wish).

Answer (score 2):

[Suexec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) can run cgi as users other than the apache user. If you want to run PHP like this you might also be interested in [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html).